windows devcontainer fails with mounting error
I am trying to open a dev container is VSCode using the following devcontainer.json:
{
    "name": "Windows Server 2022 Core",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022"
}

when I get an error message box with the following text:
A mount config is invalid. Make sure it has the right format and a source folder that exists on the machine where the docker daemon is running.
I have switched docker to "windows containers".
Tried to search the web for any solutions without any success. Any ideas would be much appreciated.
